# How to start Tomcat7 in Eclipse 4.4 under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem.

I have installed Tomcat7 with apt-get and it works fine. But, when I try to start this server from Eclipse it fails with error:

> ```
> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or
> ```
>
> incomplete. Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at
>   /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may
>   be corrupt or incomplete.

What should I do?

Comment: I am not an eclipse expert, but perhaps this [article](http://www.programering.com/a/MjMwkzMwATE.html) might be useful

Answer (score 0):

There are possible configurations that would work out for you in line with creating symbolic links to tomcat7 directories but the simplest would be you to download a tomcat tar ball, extract it in your home directory an point eclipse to it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a permission problem. You can solve this problem
by either changing the permission of tomcat installation directory or 
by changing the `ownership` of the tomcat installation directory.

Changing the ownership: 
Let's say that there is a `user: tookuk` and `group: tookuk` then 
you can change the ownership of directory from root:root to 
tookuk:tookuk like this:

```
sudo chown -R tookuk:tookuk apache-tomcat-directory/
```

for example If you have installed tomcat in `/opt/tomcat` then the command will be:

```
sudo chown -R tookuk:tookuk /opt/tomcat/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission problem because Eclipse thinks your user account has access to all of the conf files in /etc/tomcat8 (even if they are linked).  You can change the permissions on the linked folders and make sure the links are set correctly.

However, after finally getting that all to work, I realized that by NOT using the distro release of Tomcat, I could put a full server in a single directory structure (vs links to /etc/tomcat8 and /var/log/tomcat8).  This made Eclipse much happier and there was no need to update links or permissions.

Both of these solutions work, one is much simpler to set up.